# Medieval instruments samples

Tags: sound-design, music, drone

I'm working on a sound design where I want to use samples from medieval instruments to make background drones that doesn't sound too synthetic and also captures the sound of the time that the installation is about (14th century).

So my question: Does anybody have recordings of long tones from instruments like crumhorns or anything else medieval? Or anyone with an instrument who could record some long tones for me?

Answer (score 1):

They have a crumhorn as kontakt instrument on the spitfire audio website. it´s in the "spitfire labs" section, where you have to donate something like 2 pounds to unicef to get an instrument from a variety of "leftover" samples.
https://www.spitfireaudio.com/spitfire-labs-intro

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample library called "Early Patches", distributed by Best Service:

http://soundbytes.de/EarlyPatches/de/reviews.htm
(English reviews at the bottom)

You should also try "Historical Instruments" by USB:
http://www.soundstosample.com/info/Soundscan/Historical_Instruments/960

Answer (score 0):

I have no samples but you could try to google hurdy-gurgy and bagpipes. Both, especially in combination, can give a great drone sound.

Original bagpipes are medieval instruments and are different from the Scottish ones. Both instruments have a drone note combined with melody notes.